# Installing pip for an offline machine on Python 2.7, CentOS 6.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm trying to install `lxml` for Centos6.3, due to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30056737/1075247). It looks like I've got a conflicting version of pip. The standing solution seems to re-install pip for the correct version of python.

My main issue is that all the [methods](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) I've found for installing pip require an internet connection. Is it possible to download pip install files, and then run `pip install -U pip` and point it at the right files?

The  PyPI page for [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) only has pip6.11 as a `.whl`. I've tried running `pip install -U pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl` and it's not worked.

I'm stumped. How do I install it?

Comment: pip will need internet in order to work, why would you want to install it on an offline machine ?
Why don't you just install lxml without pip ?

Comment: @blusky is that even possible?

Comment: http://lxml.de/build.html

Comment: You can always download the source (sdist) distribution of `lxml`, extract it (zip) and run `python setup.py install`. @Blusky - pip also works offline and this behavior is well documented. Many enterprise Python deployments are firewalled from Internet.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa why would he needs pip, if it's for running `python setup.py install` ? Yes, pip can run offline, but why use this tool if it's needed only for one packet ?

Comment: @Blusky: Thanks! Edited my comment - there was an obvious mistake there!

Comment: @Pureferret: Please also put any error messages to your question.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I'll copy them over by hand if I get a chance later. I'm going to try to install lxml from source first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to download pip and setuptools manually from: https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files and https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/#files

get the python pip script from: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

after that unzip/untar packages and run:
`python get-pip.py --no-index --find-links=/path/to/pip-and-setuptools`

or alternatively trying:
`python setup.py install` when running in unpacked folders

More here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2351