# How to install pip for python 3.7 on an offline RHEL7 Machine

Tags: python, pip, rhel7

I have `python3.7` install on an offline `RHEL7` server that has no internet access, I need to install pip to it . all the rpms I found for `pip` targeting `python3.6` .. and it fails when I try to run `rpm -I package_name.rpm` as it expects to find `python3.6` .. any help on finding the right `rpm` package for it?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30074867/7976758) is about Python 2.7 on CentOS 6.3 but [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54690221/7976758) is quite generic. Try it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+offline